# Holomorphic function with a.e. vanishing radial boundary limits

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, examples

Hello everybody.

I'm looking for an "easy" example of a (non-zero) holomorphic function $f$ with almost everywhere vanishing radial boundary limits: $\lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 1-} f(re^{i\phi})=0$.

Does anyone know such an example.

Best
CJ

Comment: The function is not going to be in any Hardy space... So "easy"? :)

Comment: Nitpick/bad joke: the words "not identically zero" are missing

Comment: Yemon, I was about to write that... Otherwise $f\equiv 0$ is a VERY easy example... 

Comment: Yes, thank you. I ment a non-zero example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if this would qualify as 'easy' but the first example of such a function was constructed by Lusin. It can be found in N. Lusin, J. Priwaloff, [Sur l'unicité et la multiplicité des fonctions analytiques](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASENS/ASENS_1925_3_42_/ASENS_1925_3_42__143_0/ASENS_1925_3_42__143_0.pdf),  *Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup.* (3), 1925, p. 143-191 (see p. 185).

Answer (score 13):

According to a footnote in the famous Hardy-Ramanujan paper "Asymptotic formulae in combinatory analysis", the function $f(q)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^n}$ vanishes like $f(re^{i\theta})=o((1-r)^{1/4-\varepsilon})$ for almost all $\theta$. No proof is given, though I can't imagine Hardy would have made a statement like this without a proof in his pocket.

**Edit:** This isn't actually hard to guess at.  By Euler's pengatonal number theorem, we have $f(q)^{-1}=\sum_{n\in \mathbf{Z}}(-1)^{n}q^{n(3n-1)/2}$, so Plancherel gives

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^{-2}d\theta=2\pi\sum_{n\in \mathbf{Z}}r^{n(3n-1)} \sim 2 \pi^{3/2}3^{-1/2}(1-r)^{-1/2}.$

Comment: That's impressive. I was thinking of such an example myself, but then the results on the possible sets of good $\theta$'s scared me away (e.g. full measure implies first Baire category).

Comment: @David: Could you possibly indicate the page containing the footnote? I did not find it.

Comment: @Andrey: It's the asterisked footnote on the first page of Section 1.5 of the paper, which is page 281 in the AMS-Chelsea edition of Ramanujan's collected papers.

Comment: @David: Thats a very nice example. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

To complement Andrey Rekalo's response, Lusin's construction was generalized by Bagemihl and Seidel (Math. Zeitschrift 61 (1954), online [here](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/main/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002384698)). See their Corollary 4 whose proof takes about 2 pages, much less than the original one by Lusin-Priwaloff. Of course the proof relies on Mergelyan's famous approximation theorem for which see Section 20.5 in Rudin: Real and Complex Analysis.

**EDIT:** Lvriemsurf asked in a comment if we can replace "almost every angle" by "every angle" in the construction. The answer is "no", as follows from the [Lusin-Priwaloff theorems](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Luzin-Privalov_theorems).

Comment: Unfortunately I can give the credit to just one comment. Thanks to both of you. Especially for the links.

Comment: The question and the answers / links are great !

My question is : what if I replace almost all/every $\theta$ by all/every $ theta $ ? Then can we still have such a holomorphic function on $D$ whose all radial limits are zero ?

Comment: @Lvriemsurf: I edited my response and included an answer to your question.

Comment: Hi, the second link is broken.

Comment: @user111: Fixed, thank you.